# What does "tom. i." mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, abbreviations, reference-request

I'm seeing the following abbreviation in several book/manuscript citations, particularly in religious works, but I have no idea what the abbreviation means. From the context of where I'm finding it, I'm assuming it is a Latin abbreviation.  Does anyone know what it stands for?

tom. i.

Used (for example) in the following citation:
1690, tom. i. col. 1006. 25. Ejusdem Sermo * de nativitate Beate Marie.” fol. 74. b. Impress. ibid. tom. i. col. 1012. 26. Ejusdem Sermo * ad abbates et fratres.” fol. 79. b. Impress. ibid. tom. i. col. 1155. 27. Ejusdem Sermones duo * de angelis.” fol.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Emily! If you register your account, you will be able to accept an answer, vote up the questions and answers you like, and have more freedom on the site with the privileges this nice question has earned you. (Reputation points effect what you can do.) If you created a new account and registered it (as it seems), you can [merge your accounts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 15):

tomus primus = "volume one".

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I thought it might have some meaning related to "tome" but couldn't find any confirmation.